# Laravel validation: how mark as required an element of an item in array only if another is not present

Tags: laravel, validation

My api accept in post an array of recipients.

Every recipients must have email OR phone, but NOT both.

I tried this

```
'recipients'    => 'required|array|min:1',
    'recipients.*.email'     => 'required_without:recipients.*.phone',
    'recipients.*.phone'     => 'required_without:recipients.*.email',
```

The problem is that the following MUST BE discarded, but it is valid for laravel

```
{
  recipients: [
      'email': 'a'
      'phone: 'b'
  ]
}
```

If there is email MUST NOT be the phone, and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `required_unless` validator.

from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-unless)

But you have a bigger problem in that you're validating an array.  So it wont be a simple case of using the asterisk "*" in the array because you need to check the phone / email for each recipient, not any recipient.

So perhaps something like this.

```
$rules = [
    'recipients'         => 'required|array|min:1'
];

for($i = 0; $i < count(request('recipients')); $i++) {
    $rules['recipient.' . $i . '.email'] = 'required_unless:recipient.' . $i . '.phone';
    $rules['recipient.' . $i . '.phone'] = 'required_unless:recipient.' . $i . '.email';
}

return $rules;
```

Comment: No so simple. If I have phone, I MUST HAVE NOT phone.I need something like a XOR, must be mutually exlusive. I consider an error if both are valorized.